# C# two lists to use with cmd parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, list

I have two lists

```
List<TimeSpan> MovieStart, List<TimeSpan> MovieEnd
```

SQL query :

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, @MovieDuration, @MovieStartTime) MovieEndTime
FROM MovieDetails
```

Right now I'm trying to use a for-loop but I keep getting errors - can anyone help me with this?

Code I tried to use:

```
int counter = 0;

using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd3.ExecuteReader())
{
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieDuration", MovieDuration[counter]);
    cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieTime", MovieStartTime[counter]);

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        MovieEndTime.Add(rdr.GetTimeSpan(rdr.GetOrdinal("MovieEndTime")));//add to the list
    }

    counter++;
}

con.Close();
```

The error is

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@MovieDuration"

Comment: What error are you getting, and on which line?

Comment: You might want to add your parameters to your `cmd3` before executing it. Also, you seem _only_ to use your query to add two things up. Why don't you simply use C# for that? You are not selecting anything from your table with this query.

Comment: @oerkelens good idea using C#, didnt think of that..

Answer (score 0):

Easily solved thanks to orkelens's suggestion to use C#

```
for(int i = 0; i < MovieDuration.Count; i++) {
       TimeSpan MovieEndTime = MovieStartTime[i] + MovieDuration[i];
       lstMovieEndTime.Add(MovieEndTime);
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but why use a TimeSpan for something you call MovieEnd**Time**? I would expect that to be a DateTime, not a TimesSpan.

Comment: In the DB, I am using varchar for MovieDuration and the data inside are in minutes (eg. 120,140) therefore i need to convert the varchar. I am using the MovieEndTime to compare timespans later on with Current time etc .